# No Main Manifest Attribute Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file and when I double clicked on it, it didn't pop up.  I went to the terminal and did java -jar fileName.jar and it gave me the error "no main manifest attribute, in fileName.jar" even when I specified a main method when compiling a runnable jar from Eclipse Luna 4.4.

I specified the launch configuration as the main method I want to run, and the export destination onto my desktop.

Am I doing something wrong when compiling the jar file?

Comment: is it third party jar or you are creating one

Answer (score 0):

It seems your manifest file doesn't contain the main method name.
Can you post your manifest file details over here?

Comment: My file shows:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0`

`Class-Path: .`

Comment: Your Manifest File should contain three things: Manifest Version, Created By and your Class-Path. In the Class-Path part,it should contain the path of the class where you have written your main method. If its inside some package then it should be like package.class name